# Google maps API javascript integration wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I've been struggling to integrate the google maps api into a wordpress page and finally got it....sort of.

I added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=true"> </script>
```

and

```
<body <?php if (is_page('Test5')) { echo 'onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()"'; } ?>>
```

to header.php. I put them in the head section but outside of the existing php tags. BTW...the name of the page with the map is Test5.

From what I read, the second section of code should make it so the goggle maps javascript only loads on page 'Test5'. I added a dummy API key to the javascript URL to see if the script is loading on every page and sure enough it is. I get the invalid api key popup on every page.

Where did I go wrong?

Here is the code I added to the page ('Test5') using the "Text" tab. Just in case you need to see it.

```
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var map_options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I'm a noob when it comes to customizing wordpress and using google maps API so please make an explanations as noob friendly as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including the Google JavaScript on every page, but only running it on the Test5 page.  To only load it on Test5, add a check where you're enqueueing it, like this:

```
<?php if (is_page('Test5')) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=true"> </script>
<?php } ?>
```

A couple of other notes:

- It's best to use [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), rather than hardcoding it in `header.php`.  It allows people who extend your code to replace it with a different version, if necessary, without changing your code
- If I read this: `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` correctly, you're calling `initialize` on page load anyway - you shouldn't need the extra logic in the `body` tag (if you're sure you need `GUnload` you could probably do it in the same place - something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2593786/1714))

Comment: Glad to hear.  Can you accept my answer (click the check mark beside it)?  It's how we say thanks around here ;)